# How to obtain timings from a specific line in a text file and subtract it with another line in python?

Tags: python, linux, time

I have a text file in which certain data like this

```
2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0-poll-4|10/06/2015 05:32:09 pm
```

Is stored. The `2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0` is the UID and the poll-4 is the key as you can see there is a time. Another piece of data would be

```
2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0-load-5|10/06/2015 05:32:22 pm
```

as you can see the key is load-5 but the UID is the same. The text file is filled with these and what I need to be able to do is calculate the poll time difference from the load time and make sure that the poll and the load are from the same UID.Keeping in mind its from a text file.

Comment: Where is your code so far? What bit of it are you stuck with? [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

1. Open the file
2. Iterate over the lines of the file
3. Use e.g. a regular expression or manual code to parse out the information from each line
4. Store the information in memory in a Python list
5. Do the computations on the data from the list

Once you have the data in a more suitable format in a list, it's easy to search and access the list elements (corresponding to the lines of the text file) in any order.

Unless the file is so large you can't afford the memory to do this, this is the most straight-forward approach.

Very quick draft:

```
records = []
reg = re.compile(r'^([a-z0-9]{26}-([^|]+)|(.+)$')
for l in open("thefile.txt").readlines():
  mo = reg.match(l)
  if mo is not None:
    records.append(mo.groups())
```

Then look in `records`, it will be a list with one tuple per line. The fields of the tuple hold the three fields of each line.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Approach if the files are huge:

1. Split the file into poll and load generators;
2. iterate through poll, for each line iterate through load (starting only from poll time)
3. For each match calculate difference (possibly generator output again)

This approach is for the case that you don't want to load all data into memory, because it is too big or it keeps coming.

If poll and load records are away from each other by large distance, and the data file is huge, you could also store into database and index by uid.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0-poll-4|10/06/2015 05:32:09 pm"
>>> s2 = "2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0-load-5|10/06/2015 05:32:22 pm"
>>> pattern = re.compile("(\w+)(?:.*\|)(.*$)")
>>> groups = pattern.match(s1).groups()
>>> groups
('2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0', '10/06/2015 05:32:09 pm')
>>> groups2 =  pattern.match(s2).groups()
>>> groups[0] == groups2[0]
True
>>> timeformat = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time1 = datetime.strptime(groups[1], timeformat)
>>> time2 = datetime.strptime(groups2[1], timeformat)
>>> time2 - time1
datetime.timedelta(0, 13)
```

Comment: But the text file contains different UID with different keys not only load and poll key all I need is to find a UID which has a poll key and a load key but that code only allows you to do it once, i need to be able to search for that criteria and then with the UIDS that match find the time difference

Comment: My example shows you how to extract the IDs and the times using a regular expression, and then compare them to each other. If you look at the other answers there are some suggestions about how to loop through the text file and process every line. Try to combine those ideas with these.

Comment: If you remove the `?:` from the regex I gave, so you have `"(\w+)(.*\|)(.*$)"`, the tuple returned by `groups()` will contain the "key" as well, which should help. (e.g. `('2t05sj7jh36pl7qti1e5n9j6j0', '-load-5', '10/06/2015 05:32:09 pm')`)

Comment: `"(\w+)-(.*)\|(.*$)"` might ultimately be more useful as it cuts out the delimiter characters.